# How do I store information securely on android device?

Tags: android, storage

I want to store information on an android device. What is the best way to store data so that the user is not able to access (write/read) the files.

I've looked at Shared preferences and SQLite Database , these seem like they  might be viable options.

Thanks
Fabii

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear on the device itself. The device is a Logitech revue. Not a cell phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no best way to store secure data as a user with rooted phone will always have access to your data. So the best bet would be to do some kind of **Encryption** on your secret data to make it useless even if its accessed by others.

For Encryption/Decryption, read [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings).

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear on the device itself. The device is a Logitech revue. Not a cell phone.

Comment: I'm overall talking about Android framework. So the danger of **Rootness** still applies :)

Comment: Does android not provide any secure application space?

Comment: On an Unrooted phone/device, application's cache folder within device's internal memory is considered as secured storage...

Comment: Okay on an unrooted device, if I was to store information using shared preferences. Is it easy for the user to navigate to these files?

Comment: anything is possible (piece of cake) to access (at least in terms of file structure) on a rooted device