# How store the data in android device securely?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, secure-gateway

I have the problem to store the downloaded data in my android device Now I store the data on my sdcard, but this is not much prevent from the user. I need to store the data securely from the user. How can I do that?

Comment: Check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607613/is-there-a-way-to-securely-store-user-data-on-an-android-device  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909446/how-do-i-store-information-securely-on-android-device http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+store+the+data+in+android+device+securely%3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way you can prevent the user from accessing your data. The max you can do is :

1. Make the folders you create as hidden ( prefix the folder names with a `.`  )
2. remove the extension of the files you create, if possible. In most cases you can still access them & your files dont show up in other apps (like music players, Image viewers).

Comment: That's the max you can do? What about encrypting the files? I know it is not 100% secure but is better than just hide the files

Comment: I agree. Encryption could be the better option.It depends on how sensitive the data is. My answer could be a simpler solution for, say, a game which downloads a few images from a server, but the user might not want these images to show up in the Gallery app and so on..

Answer (score 0):

For storing senstive data or some downloaded dat in the application , just use internal Storage. ie "data/data/{App package name}/{direcdtory name}". if you store data inside the internal storage, only your application can access the data not the user nor other application.